# Why does my cell shifts to the right when i resize it?

Tags: css

I'm trying to resize a cell like this:

```
margin:5px;
padding:1px;
border: solid 2px;
color:blue;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
max-width:50px;
```

The border of the cell follows the CSS settings but the actual cell seem to spill out of the container to the right. Any ideas how I can get the cell to have the same width of its container? I'm a bit confused because i thought that the `<td>` tag was actually the cell.

Comment: can you show a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: `td` elements are cells, yes (*), so what caused the confusion?  There are some properties that don't work well, or not at all, on table cells, like `position` and `margin`. Also, `max-width` is used as a rough guideline rather than a hard limit, so it might not be possible to resize the cell at all in this way. You may have to resize the content.

Comment: (*) Well, Unless you give them a `display` property, then they no longer are table cells. But I don't think that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to format the cells that contain @html.textbox and @html.textboxfor using the following css and directly in the view:

```
#allAttendanceGradeHead
{
     border-collapse:collapse;
margin:1px;
padding:1px;
border: solid 2px #a8adfd;
color:Green;
 max-width: 100px;

  text-align:center;
}


 #homeworkGradeCell
 {

   border-collapse:collapse;
margin:1px;
padding:1px;
border: solid 2px;
border-color: Fuchsia;
background-color:Yellow;
 max-width:200px;



  text-align:center;

}
```

And in the view:

```
 <td id="homeworkGradeCell" style=" border-color:Lime">
                 @Html.TextBox("HomeworkGrade", "100", new { style = "width:60px; color:red; text-align: center" })

                 @if (@ViewBag.NumberErrorMessage != null)
                 {
                         <div id="numberRequiredMessage">
                               @ViewBag.NumberErrorMessage

                          </div>
                 }

       </td>
```

And here’s the @html.textboxfor…

```
 #attendanceCodeCell
{

      color:Maroon;
    max-width:2px;
     position:relative;
     border: solid 2px #a8adfd;
    }
    And in the view:

 <td id="attendanceCodeCell">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.attendanceCode, new { Value = "1",style ="      width:12px; border-color:red"})
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.attendanceCode)

       </td>
```